# How to get class name of the WebElement in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium WebDriver to scrape a table taken from a web page, written in JavaScript.

I am iterating on a list of table rows. Each row may be of a different class. I want to get the name of this class so that I can choose appropriate action for each row.

```
table_body = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
for row in rows:
    if (row.GetClassName()=="date"):
        Action1()
    else:
        Action2()
```

Is this possible with Selenium? Or suggest another approach.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[`.get_attribute()` method](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) is what you are looking for:

```
row.get_attribute("class")
```